# First year physics: mechanic + electric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism

I did a practice paper and I don't have solutions, I just want to make sure that I'm doing them right. Thank you. (had to translate these questions from German)

1. How much work is needed to cause an electron (mass: 9.11e-31kg) to move at a velocity of 1.4e6m/s

Work = Change in Kinetic Energy
     = Kinetic Energy Final - Kinetic Energy Initial

Therefore it's simply. (0.5*electron mass*velocity^2)

2. A thin homogenous stick with a mass of 2.0kg and length 60cm is perpendicularly positioned on a frictionless table. It's let go and falls. Calculate the velocity of it's center of mass right before it touches the table.

[image]

For this question I'm not really sure?? I was thinking of the formula Vm = (sum of velocity * mass)/ sum of mass

3. A square wire loop is placed next to a wire. In both wires flows a current of 1.5A. Calculate the force and it's direction.

[image]

Direction of force: Downwards
F = I * L x B

B = μ0/2pi I/d = μ0/2pi 1,5A/0.03m = 1e-5

F = 1.5A * 0.1m * 1e-5T =1.5e-6N

4. An iron casting containing a number of cavities weighs 6000 N in air and 4000 N in water. What is the total volume of all the cavities in the casting? The density of iron is 7.9e3 kg/m^3

V = F/(density of iron * g) = 6000/(7.9e3*9.8) = 0.61